# Java String.replaceAll to append prefix and suffix based on pattern

Tags: java, regex

I have a String like this

```
DEBUG-172- {com.xyz.testing.test1} - server {logger msg}
DEBUG-122- {com.xyz.testing.test2} - server {logger message}
DEBUG-162- {com.xyz.testing.t1} - server {logger mg}
DEBUG-178- {com.xyz.testing.t2} - server {logger text}
```

I need to convert this into like this,

```
DEBUG-172- <span>{com.xyz.testing.test1}</span> - server {logger msg}
DEBUG-122- <span>{com.xyz.testing.test2}</span> - server {logger message}
DEBUG-162- <span>{com.xyz.testing.t1}</span> - server {logger mg}
DEBUG-178- <span>{com.xyz.testing.t2}</span> - server {logger text}
```

How to do this in Java?

I tried the below one, but it didn't work.

```
data = data.replaceAll("(?<=\\{com)([^\\}]+)(?=\\})", "<span>$1</span>");
```

It produces result like

```
DEBUG-172- {com<span>.xyz.testing.test1</span>} - server {logger msg}
DEBUG-122- {com<span>.xyz.testing.test2</span>} - server {logger message}
DEBUG-162- {com<span>.xyz.testing.t1</span>} - server {logger mg}
DEBUG-178- {com<span>.xyz.testing.t2</span>} - server {logger text}
```

simply saying, I need to add `<span>` before `{com` and `</span>` after its corresponding `}`.

Comment: What did you try? And what exactly do you want to achieve? Insert something before each DEBUG token, or on each newline?

Comment: Updated the question Markus

Comment: Are the braces nested?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Problem is that look-around mechanisms are [zero-length](http://www.regular-expressions.info/zerolength.html) (they are not included in match, you can also think of it like they set cursor to its original position before it entered look-around).

So don't use it. Simply let your group start with `{com` and end with `}`. In between you can accept any character which is not `}` (we don't want to include more than one `}`).

Also you don't need additional capturing group. Entire match is stored by default in group 0 and you can access it via `$0`.

So your code should look more like

```
data = data.replaceAll("\\{com[^\\}]+\\}", "<span>$0</span>");
```

Answer (score 2):

The following will likely do what you want:

```
data.replaceAll("\\{com[^}]*\\}", "<span>$0</span>");
```

Also be aware that this will fall flat on its face when the braces are nested. It can't be solved with regex in general, then.

Comment: We don't need additional capturing group. Entire match is by default stored in group 0.

Comment: True, but it doesn't hurt.

Comment: I am not saying that it may hurt (much, since it will add little more work). I am pointing that it is not needed :)